# A definite integration problem on law of large number

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The problem is given as follows:

> If $g(x),h(x)$ are continuous function on $[0,1]$, satisfying $0\le g(x) <M h(x)$, where $M$ is a nonzero constant. Prove that
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^1 \int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\frac{g(x_1)+g(x_2)+\cdots +g(x_n)}{h(x_1)+h(x_2)+\cdots +h(x_n)}dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n=\frac{\int_{0}^1g(x)dx}{\int_0^1h(x)dx}$$

I have some idea of the solution, but I think there must be some problem. Here is my solution:

Let $T_i$ be the random variables with density function $\frac{g(x)}{\int_{0}^1 g(t)dt}$ , where $x\in[0,1]$.Similarly, we define $S_i$, with density function $\frac{h(x)}{\int_{0}^1 h(t)dt}$.

By the law of large numbers, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n T_i=1 \mbox{  a.s,}\lim_{n\to\infty} B_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n S_i=1 \mbox{  a.s}$$

But I got stuck here, because I cannot combine the two result to get the solution, it does not mean anything since the density function cannot be divided directly. Is there any method to tackle this problem?

Any hint of a solution is welcomed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This was already posted on the site.) Consider an i.i.d. sequence $(U_n)$ uniform on $(0,1)$, then the $n$th integral on the LHS is $E[W_n]$, where
$$
W_n=\frac{g(U_1)+\cdots+g(U_n)}{h(U_1)+\cdots+h(U_n)}.
$$
You already know that $W_n\to w$ almost surely, where $w$ is the RHS. Furthermore, $0\leqslant W_n\leqslant M$ almost surely hence $W_n\to w$ in $L^1$, which implies that $E[W_n]\to w$.